# C/C++ Open Source Project(e.g. SFML) compilation and run question

Tags: c++, compilation, sfml

Recently, I'm learning C/C++ programming, and I used the SFML framework. I want to use SFML through the source code, i.e. compile it from source code.I read the compile instruction from the website, and got the messages below:

> On Linux however, nothing is provided and SFML relies on your own
> installation of the libraries it depends on. Here is a list of what
> you need to install before compiling SFML:
>
> pthread opengl xlib udev xrandr xcursor freetype openal flac vorbis

I know that to get the SFML source code to be compiled, I have to install the dependency libraries, and then use the compiled library to build my own application.
But, I have a question about my final application.If others use my developed application, do they have to install the dependency libraries that is dependent by SFML?

> pthread opengl xlib udev xrandr xcursor freetype openal flac vorbis

Comment: Doesn't your distro have these libraries? I would expect it to already have these. You may need -dev packages for the headers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your idea. To build SFML from source, I need to install pthread, opengl, xlib... .I make my distro using SFML library, and maybe static linking. So If another one use my distro, does his machine need to install "pthread, opengl, xlib.." libraries that is needed by SFML build procedure?

Comment: What I was saying is a linux distribution like Ubuntu will have all of the listed library dependencies available in its package manager so you don't have to download compile yourself.

Comment: Yes, if another one use my diestro, does he need to install these libraries manually if his os doesn't have these libraries installed?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really answer this with certainty, but if you want to check stuff like this for yourself you can download a virtualbox image of windows 10 for free which is preinstalled and just has to be imported. you can then just drag and drop your .exe into this system and try to run it ^^ if you get dependency errors you can check those ^^